# (Parse/Android) How can I query for the latest 15th data?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have the following method to query the list of items in the onCreate method of the chat activity and set it as my adapter:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat,container,false);

    ListView chatListView = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.chatListView);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, messages);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Message");
    query.setLimit(15);
    query.orderByAscending("createdAt");
    query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", new Date());

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                if(objects.size() > 0){

                    messages.clear();

                    for (ParseObject message : objects){

                        messages.add(message.getString("sender") + ": " + message.getString("content"));

                    }

                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            } else {
                // Something is wrong
            }
        }
    });

    chatListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

The result I get is the first 15 data instead of the latest 15.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

use ordery by desc  instead asc:

```
 query.orderByAscending("createdAt");
```

use this:

```
query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt");
```

Comment: but how do you get them in order?

Comment: Descending guve last data created in order